# setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnedIntent) from child activity always return me an Activity.CANCELED to main activity

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I want to return some data from my child Activity `ActivityChild` to my main Activity `ActivityMain`

I first call my `ActivityChild` from my `ActivityMain` this way :

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
// Actually, this code first launch chrome, then when the user identify on
// chrome, the redirect_uri calls the ActivityChild
```

then, I return my data from `ActivityChild` to `ActivityMain` this way :

```kotlin
val data: Uri? = intent.data
val returnedIntent = Intent();
returnedIntent.putExtra("code", data!!.getQueryParameter("code"))
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnedIntent)
finish()
```

and finally I catch the data with an override of onActivityResult in `ActivityMain` :

```kotlin
public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val returnedValue = data!!.getStringExtra("data")
        }
        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
            Log.d("mDebug", "Couldn't retrieve data") // Always enters here
        else
            Log.d("mDebug", "final")
    }
}
```

It keep going in the `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` condition. I can't manage to resolve this, if it is resolvable.

I believe the cause is from the fact that I first launch chrome via the intent and that somehow data can't be transfered to the `ActivityMain`. I'm far from nowing everything concerning intents and I'm probably missing something here, so if someone could help me and explain it please !

Comment: Have you changed the launch mode of ActivityChild?

Comment: How should I change the launch mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @Bach Vu and this post : [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT and PendingIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488618/intent-flag-activity-forward-result-and-pendingintent) I manage to get what I wanted using Shared Preferencies. I'm stocking my data in the shared preferencies in the `ActivityChild` and the retrieving it in my `ActivityMain` using the override of onActivityResult

Answer (score 0):

You can consider adding this flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` to your `returnedIntent`. It is described here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT

> If set and this intent is being used to launch a new activity from an existing one, then the reply target of the existing activity will be transferred to the new activity. This way, the new activity can call Activity.setResult(int) and have that result sent back to the reply target of the original activity.

Comment: I added returnedIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT in my child activity but it sadly doesn't work

Comment: Why child activity? You should put it in the intent when `startActivityForResult`

Comment: Because it makes the application crash

Comment: What's the crash log?

Comment: "FORWARD_RESULT_FLAG used while also requesting a result" I just want to clarify how my activities are called : ActivityMain launches google chrome via the intent. When the user logs in, the redirection calls the ActivityChild. From the ActivityChild I want to send back data to ActivityMain. Hope this help